# Google OAuth fails in WP8.1.Runtime or WinStoreApp 8.1

Tags: oauth, google-oauth

I have a sample for google authentication and it worked, but now it fails and not understood why.

Now it gives something like

https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/approval?as=XXXXXXXXXXXX=en_US&pageId=none&xsrfsign=YYYYYYYYYYYYYY

and before was something with

```
 code=4/ZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZ
```

I am using

```
GoogleClientId = TTTTTTTTT
GoogleCallbackUrl = "urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob";

var googleUrl = "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?client_id=" + Uri.EscapeDataString(GoogleClientId) + "&redirect_uri=" + Uri.EscapeDataString(GoogleCallbackUrl) + "&response_type=code&scope=" + Uri.EscapeDataString("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile");

var startUri = new Uri(googleUrl);
var endUri = new Uri("https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/approval?");
```

What is wrong or changed?

Comment: it's strange, I follow the documentation.
You can see it here:
https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2InstalledApp#formingtheurl
and
https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2InstalledApp#handlingtheresponse

Comment: I think your scope is incorrect. See here: https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2Login#scope-param

Comment: Also your callbackUri, see https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2Login#redirect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I need to do

```
  #if !WINDOWS_PHONE_APP 
       public const string GoogleCallbackUrl = "urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob"; 
   #else 
        public const string GoogleCallbackUrl = "http://localhost"; 
   #endif
```

and then

```
        public async Task<Session> LoginAsync() 
        { 
            var googleUrl = new StringBuilder(); 
            googleUrl.Append("https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?client_id="); 
            googleUrl.Append(Uri.EscapeDataString(Constants.GoogleClientId)); 
            googleUrl.Append("&scope=openid%20email%20profile"); 
            googleUrl.Append("&redirect_uri="); 
            googleUrl.Append(Uri.EscapeDataString(Constants.GoogleCallbackUrl)); 
            googleUrl.Append("&state=foobar"); 
            googleUrl.Append("&response_type=code"); 

            var startUri = new Uri(googleUrl.ToString()); 


#if !WINDOWS_PHONE_APP 
           var endUri = new Uri("https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/approval?"); 
           var webAuthenticationResult = await WebAuthenticationBroker.AuthenticateAsync(WebAuthenticationOptions.UseTitle, startUri, endUri); 
           return await GetSession(webAuthenticationResult); 
#else 
            WebAuthenticationBroker.AuthenticateAndContinue(startUri, new Uri(Constants.GoogleCallbackUrl), null, WebAuthenticationOptions.None); 
            return null; 
#endif
```

see the complete code here:
http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Authentication-using-bb28840e

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your scope and callbackUri are not correct. The scope should be an openid format. See [this doc](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2Login#scope-param) for more info on scope.

It also looks like your callback is not correct. The callback needs to be a url. The json file you download has an urn in it, but if view your credentials online, you will notice a redirect uri (I have localhost). See [this doc](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2Login#redirect) for more an redirect.

This request worked fine for me:

> https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?client_id=random.apps.googleusercontent.com&redirect_uri=http://localhost&scope=openid%20profile%20email&state=foobar&response_type=code

Comment: Thanks for the help, that url works for Windows Phone 8.1 Runtime but not for Windows Store Apps 8.1... you can see final result here: http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Authentication-using-bb28840e